# Measuring memory and CPU used by a Java console application with java.lang.management 

Tags: java, performance, monitoring

I need to measure how much memory and CPU my application is using at the moment, and I need to measure that from the very same application. Any advices how to do that? I've been using jconsole, but I can't find an API which would enable me to use it from a console application.

Thanks.

EDIT: As the user **aix** recommended, I'm using `java.lang.management` to achieve my goal. However, I have few questions about it. This is the code I wrote:

```
MemoryMXBean bean = ManagementFactory.getMemoryMXBean();
MemoryUsage memoryUsage = bean.getHeapMemoryUsage();
double used = (double)memoryUsage.getUsed() / (1024 * 1024); // in MB
double max = (double)memoryUsage.getMax() / (1024 * 1024); // in MB
```

I'm calling this from the application that I want to measure. What exactly does this measure? Memory taken by the whole application? By the current thread?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for the [Java Virtual Machine Monitoring and Management API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/management/index.html).

In particular, take a look at [`MemoryMXBean`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/management/MemoryMXBean.html) and [`ThreadMXBean`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/management/ThreadMXBean.html).

Comment: This will help, thanks! Can you please look at my updated question?

Comment: @Ivan: AFAIK there's no such metric as "heap used by thread X" (how would you attribute objects that are shared by several threads or passed between threads).